# Can I reference an imported type without using dot notation

Tags: go, namespaces

Consider the following interface definition:

```golang
package repos

import (
  resources "unit/pkg/resources"
)

type IRepo interface {
  fetch(int32) (resources.IResource, error)
  update(resources.IResource) (resources.IResource, error)
  new() resources.IResource
  create(resources.IResource) (resources.IResource, error)
  delete(int32) error
}
```

Is there a way to 'use' the imported package (in the sense of C++ namespaces), so that I don't need to explicitly name it using dot notation each time I reference one of its types (`IResource`)

(TBH - this may just mean that `IResource` belongs in the `repos` package and not in `resources`)

Comment: Would it be silly to just define a new package-local type? eg - `type RepoResource resources.IResource`?

Comment: If you need this, you may have a design flaw, or you may just not be used to Go. Referencing namespaced types is how Go works normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a type alias.

```
type IRes = resources.IResource
```

In contrast to a type definition, an alias is just another name for the same type and not a new distinct type. A type definition would be without the `=`.

Comment: @donny-nyc, note that type aliases are not really intended for this, they are mostly used for refactoring and compatibility. The code should be written to favor the reader, and using a type alias simply to avoid having to type the package identifier makes it unclear what the intent of the code is.

Comment: This is a very bad advice as it missuses a language feature.

Comment: @Volker Even if I do agree with you to some extent. I would myself prefer being explicit and a bit more verbose. Still, that standpoint is also somewhat opinion. AFAIK there is no other way to achieve what OP asks for, and he did explicitly ask for a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can prefix the [`import` declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) with the name `.` to import all of its identifiers:

```golang
package repos

import (
  . "unit/pkg/resources"
)
```

---

*However,* `import .` is almost never the appropriate solution. If new identifiers are added to the `resources` package in the future, they can collide with existing identifiers in the `repos` package and break your build.

Furthermore, the fact that the package name is redundant with the type name may indicate that either the package or the types within that package should have a better name (see the [Package names](https://blog.golang.org/package-names) blog post for much more detail).

In this case, perhaps the abstraction boundary between `resources` and `repos` is doing more harm than good. What *kind* of resources are you dealing with here? Could the `Resource` type be moved into some higher-level package?

---

Finally, I would note that the `IRepo` interface seems very large and likely out-of-place. Go interfaces — unlike, say, Java interfaces — generally belong with the API that *consumes* the interface, not the API that *provides* implementations of that interface.

For more on that principle, see:

- https://golang.org/wiki/CodeReviewComments#interfaces
- https://hyeomans.com/golang-and-interfaces-misuse/
- https://dave.cheney.net/2016/08/20/solid-go-design
- https://dave.cheney.net/practical-go/presentations/gophercon-israel.html#_prefer_single_method_interfaces

Comment: Please do not promote bad habits.

Comment: I believe I both answered the actual question that was asked, and also explained why the question itself may warrant a different approach. I don't think it would benefit anyone to omit either of those parts.